# Flex : any way to control JSON.stringify ordering?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

Is there any way to control the ordering of the serialization in Flex's `JSON.serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is about Adobe ( pre-Fex 4.8 ) JSON - maybe overriding the method would do, but I would suggest using some free JSON implementation project, and replace the order to match best your needs, or just close the Flex 4.8 from Apache and create a mirroring class with your replacement into the implementation.